# How to export table datas to txt(or)csv files? Only Last query resultsets got exported into file?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, db2, export-to-csv

I am new Bash shell script and exporting the table datas into txt file.

```
db2 "export to $filename of del messages msg.txt select * from students_table"
```

file Contains
**"FirstName","23","Pass"**

Again i am using the same file name

> $filename

```
 db2 "export to $filename of del messages msg.txt select * from employees_table"
```

Now the output is **"EmployeeName","25,000","Salaried"**
Only last query result set got printed.

Expected Output is

1. **"FirstName","23","Pass"**
2. **"EmployeeName","25,000","Salaried"**

help me to resolve this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EXPORT command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html) overwrites the file if it exists:

> TO filename
>
> ...
>
> If the name of a file that exists is specified, the export utility overwrites the contents of the file; it does not append the information.